# Recursividad, cambio de valores?

Tags: recursión

Al ejecutar este código recursivo, que consisten en encontrar la posición del máximo de un array de enteros, cuando hace la vuelta hacia atrás ("volviendo a la llamada anterior"), cambia el valor hallado.

¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo, o dónde esta mi error?.

```
public static int findMax(int[] array, int start, int end, int index) {
    int max = array[index];
    if (start <= end) {
        if (max < array[start]) {
            findMax(array, start + 1, end, start);
        } else {
            findMax(array, start + 1, end, index);
        }
    }
    return index;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En todos los casos devuelves el valor de `index` como el resultado de la función `findMax`.
Sin embargo, cuando se debe calcular el máximo de manera recursiva, no guardas el valor calculado en ninguna variable, y deberías guardarla en `index`, o directamente devolverla mediante una instrucción `return`.

```
public static int findMax(int[] array, int start, int end, int index)
{
    if (start < end)
    {
        if (array[index] < array[start]) index = findMax(array, start + 1, end, start);
        else index = findMax(array, start + 1, end, index);
    }
    return index;
}
```

Comment: Vale, gracias he entendido lo que pasaba. Gracias por tu tiempo.